Error while running tests java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/requests/AlterPartitionRequest$Builder
Using spring boot 2.7.18 and below mentioned spring kafka test and scala library dependency.
artifact = "spring-kafka-test",
group = "org.springframework.kafka",
version = 2.9.3,

artifact = "scala-library",
group = "org.scala-lang",
version = "2.13.13"

Error:

Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:94)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/requests/AlterPartitionRequest$Builder
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:116)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:333)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:605)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:374)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/requests/AlterPartitionRequest$Builder
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:320)
at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createServer(TestUtils.scala:178)
at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createServer(TestUtils.scala:173)
at kafka.utils.TestUtils.createServer(TestUtils.scala)
at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:350)
at 

Tried some different versions but no help, any idea what can be the solution to this?

Are you using Maven? If so what does your POM looks like? Same if SBT, what does your build.sbt looks like? When does the error happen? Tests? Runtime? We need more information to help you.

Using bazel and currently trying to upgrade from bazel5 to bazel6.
This error happens while running unit tests. Tests are internally dependent on EmbeddedKafka which is causing this error. My hunch is that there's some mismatch between Spring kafka version and scala-library version.

I don't see why Scala version would be involved. It's purely Kafka class that is not present here. I'd recommend running some kind of dependency tree to identify potential version conflicts for Kafka libs.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623557/spring-kafka-2-9-3-noclassdeffound-alterisrrequestbuilder-on-embeddedkafka-st
